# Redirect coldfusion page after a timeout

Tags: coldfusion

Can I set a particular coldfusion page to redirect after a certain amount of execution time?

It runs a process that can take a long time, but I want to allow it 60 seconds to attempt it then direct it to a new page that will indicate how much of the operation was completed.

Comment: You could thread the processes that are long running and redirect the request to a page indicating the process may still be running.

Comment: Following up on @ScottStroz's comment, if you actually succeed at this, what's the user's next step if the operation times out and he gets a progress report?

Comment: It's sort of an odd scenario, the user manually fills out the processes that were missed - The part of the process that takes a long time is a cffile copy command. The number of files copied varies, and if there are more than a couple it tends to take longer than to let the user do it manually. (I'm not sure why this is)

Comment: @ScottStroz I like that idea. It's not exactly what I asked, but it does remedy the problem.

Comment: @PatrickSchomburg I try to provide solutions that solve the problem being discussed, which may not necessarily be the same as the question being asked.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what you are after here but another thought might be to *flush* the available output to the user as it is processing. ColdFusion has a tag for this to make it easy.

[See the docs regarding the cfflush tag](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7d4e.html).

It can send back information at a specific interval that you define.

> interval (Optional)
>
> Integer. Flushes output each time this number of bytes becomes available. HTML headers, and data that is already available when the tag is executed, are omitted from the count.

Comment: I'm not actually outputting any data, it's a sequence of queries followed by a cflocation tag when they are done.

Comment: If there is no user interaction (no output to the user) then it sounds like this just needs to be a scheduled task. You could have the task send an email to the person(s) when it is complete.  Perhaps the email could also contain a link for the person to click to view the report or whatever this is.

Answer (score -1):

Something real simple would be to use a META refresh.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60;url=http://yoursite.com/somepage.cfm">
```

Or, you could use Javascript:

```
setTimeout(function(){ location.href="http://yoursite.com/somepage.cfm" }, 60000);
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem outlined. This will force the client to redirect when the client is idle for 60 seconds. OP wants to know if he can redirect the server request if it takes longer than 60 seconds to complete.